# Boolean difference tool leaves open gap when performed with multiple objects

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

[image][image]enter image description here[image]After boolean difference or intersect, the intersected areas do not close up with faces but stay  open with gaps. Is this due to trying to boolean multiple objects at once? they were all connected by as one object but not vertex connected.

please help..thank you!

Comment: The boolean modifier can have issues when dealing with complex intersections and closely overlapping geometry. There are ways to get around it, but I can't discern what's going on from your screenshots.

Comment: I added two more screen shots. Those multiple strands of objects are suppose to be hair and I want to use boolean tool to make space for the head of a figurine when 3d printed. I made the hair by using a plane and adding thickness to it. Duplicated them to stack on top of each other.

Comment: I see, then why not apply the modifier to convert the first hair to a mesh, then duplicate that to create the second layer? This may be destructive editing, but as long as you store a backup of the hair before applying the modifier, it ought to be alright.

Comment: I've tried difference boolean modifier with the first hair but it leaves open surface  like the second one (second one is actually identical to the first hair. I made a mistake by applying the modifier to the sphere). I think I'm going to try sculpting from a sphere into a hair. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You could also try using the *Particle Emitter* modifier if you haven't already tried doing so. Good luck with your project!